# Should I use series of if-statements for checking IndexOutOfBounds errors?

Tags: java, string

Basically, I have a sequence of String operations, each operation that could end up with an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

My best option right now seems to be using an if-statement to check the arguments before each operation. I could surround the whole block with a try-catch, but it seems messy.

**Given an input string such as: `"http://website.web.com/num/123.3/1-2-3.1/something/"`, I want the output to be: `123.3/1-2-3.1` (numbers after the num)**

Code now:

```
URL a = new URL(url);
String b = a.getPath();
int c = b.indexOf("num/")
if (c == -1) {
  return null;
}

if (b.length() < c + 4) {
  return null;
}
String d = b.substring(c + 4);
if (d.indexOf("/") == -1) {
  return null;
}
int e = d.indexOf("/", d.indexOf("/") + 1)
if (e == -1) {
  return None
}
String f = d.substring(0, e)
return f;
```

**Having so many separate if-statements is messy, but is there a better solution to account for potential IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions?**

[Please ignore nit style such as variable names]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Regex instead:

```
String b = new URL(url).getPath();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("num/(.*?/.*?)/").matcher(b);
if (m.find()) {
    return m.group(1);
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Would prefer to not use a regular expression - for coding guidelines

Comment: What kind of guidelines don't let you use regex? What are the constraints we're working with?

Comment: Overuse of regex, too complex of regex can have a negative impact on maintainability, but this is a really simple case and excluding regex by policy here is, IMO, bad policy.